# Pathwise almost sure bound of a solution to an SDE

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Assume that $X:(\mathbb R^+ \times \Omega) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a solution to an SDE of the form $dX = \mu(X,t)  dt + \sigma(X,t)dW$ where $\mu, \sigma$ are continuous, Lipschitz continuous in the first variable (with a Lip constant idependent of $t$) and satisfy $||\mu(x,t)|| \le c||x|| +1 $ and $||\sigma(x,t)|| \le c||x|| +1 $ for some $c>0$ independent of $t$.

---

**Q:**  Can we deduce that from here that, for almost every $\omega \in \Omega$ there exists $p(\omega)>0$ such that $X(t, \omega) \exp(-p(\omega)t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$?

---

In the deterministic case, this follows from the Gronwall lemma. I don't know if it is of any help, but it also resembles the exponential bound that one can obtain for semigroups of operators (via uniform boundedness), hence I assume that a proof could involve a Baire Category Theorem-like argument.

Comment: This is not what you are asking,  but still it could help you. The following result appears in Theorem $V.2.4.$ of Ikeda & Watanabe's "Stochastic differential equations and diffusion processes".

Assume $E(|X(0)|^2)<\infty$.

Then :

$$E(|X(t)|^2)\leq (1+E(|X(0)|^2)e^{ct}-1$$ for some constant $c>0$.

Hence from here you could obtain the following 
$$E(|X(t)|^2)e^{-2ct}\leq (1+E(|X(0)|^2)e^{-ct}-e^{-2ct}$$


$$E(|X(t)e^{-ct}|^2)\leq (1+E(|X(0)|^2)e^{-ct}-e^{-2ct}$$

Letting $t\to \infty$ the RHS goes to $0$.

Hence $X(t)e^{-ct} \to 0$ in quadratic mean.

Comment: two things, I've realized that the theorem is actually in chapter IV, and the fact that since there's convergence in L2 there will be a subsequence converging a.s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The desired convergence holds even with a non-random constant in the exponent.

Indeed, the well-known estimates (see e.g. Theorem 2.2 in N. Touzi, A. Tourin *Optimal Stochastic Control, Stochastic Target Problems, and Backward SDE*) give
$$
\mathrm E \biggl[\sup_{t\in [0,T]} ||X_t||^2\biggr]\le K e^{KT}.
$$
Therefore, using Tonelli's theorem, 
$$
\mathrm E \biggl[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup_{t\in [0,n]} ||X_t||^2 e^{-2Kn}\biggr]  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm E \biggl[\sup_{t\in [0,n]} ||X_t||^2\biggr] e^{-2Kn}<\infty,
$$
whence 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup_{t\in [0,n]} ||X_t||^2 e^{-2Kn} <\infty
$$
almost surely. In particular, $\sup_{t\in [0,n]} ||X_t||^2 e^{-2Kn}\to 0, n\to\infty$, almost surely. Consequently, 
$$
||X_t|| e^{-Kt} \to 0, t\to \infty,
$$
almost surely.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please provide a reference for the first estimate?

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski, see the updated answer.